# NSURl urlWithString replaces body with dots

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to convert NSString to NSURL however I receive truncated url.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:music.url];
```

If I make NSLog music.url I get:

> /Users/Nikita/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D93FE148-7F72-43BB-A545-06D76C71300B/data/Containers/Data/Application/48BC6629-F054-4679-AC7B-709815EC5E2A/Library/Caches/4219609-357670045.mp3

And when NSLog received url:

> /Users/Nikita/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D93FE148-7F72-43BB-A545-06D76C71300B/data/Containers/Data/Applicat ... 0045.mp3

The link is partially truncated.

What is the reason?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`music.ulr` is obviously an instance of `NSString`. `url` is an instance of `NSURL`. Using `NSLog()` an instance of a class makes its own decision how to be logged.

> Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise. Also works with CFTypeRef objects, returning the result of the CFCopyDescription function.

`NSLog()` prints only a description, not the complete object, whatever this should be.

Obviously the developer of `NSString` thought, that it is a good idea to print out the complete string and wrote a description method doing that. The developer of `NSURL`thought that it is enough to print the string partially, so you can recognize it.

Comment: Amen; `[NSObject description]` is one of the most misunderstood methods in entire API and the cause of much confusion.